# Is there any reason to declare a method virtual without inheritance?

Tags: c++

Is there any reason to declare a method `virtual` if a class has no subclasses, and is always used directly?

For example:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    virtual void DoBar {
      // Do something here.
    }
}
```

I came across this in some code I was reading, and couldn't find any justification.

Thanks!

Comment: If you don't use `final`, sure.  You then pretty much *have* to declare the destructor virtual for example.  You can't predict the future.  Do use final, that locks in the future and shows that you thought about it.  Just as `virtual` shows that you thought about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Using **virtual** doesn't necessarily indicate you "thought about it". In my experience I've seen developers use **virtual** as the default because they couldn't be bothered to think about it. Hell, when I first learnt Java, it took the approach to the extreme and all methods were virtual by default without even being marked as such! It seemed the objective was to remove thinking altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the essence of `virtual` keyword is directly related to inheritance. This is an extract from [CPP Ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/polymorphism/):-

> Virtual members A virtual member is a member function that can be
>   redefined in a derived class, while preserving its calling properties
>   through references. The syntax for a function to become virtual is to
>   precede its declaration with the virtual keyword

So IMHO - the ans to your question is no - it makes no sense - unless the code has changed from initial implementation - and trust me that happens a lot!

Comment: The code might also be violating YAGNI... Make that virtual now so that some hypothetical future subclass can perhaps override if it wishes.

Comment: Accepting this answer because it was the most helpful to my situation - confirmed that there's no weird reason related to function inlining or anything.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful when writing library code to keep the future programmer in mind who may want to extend the class and provide their own behaviour. For example it is common to have a virtual `Paint()` function or virtual mouse handling functions in GUI libraries. They provide default implementations, but they allow the possibility of extension.

Answer (score 1):

If that class is meant to be derive from then yes it makes sense. These decisions should be made when deciding the architecture of a program, and defining what can be done with the interfaces. If they do not want this to be derived from then it should not be virtual. If they do want it to be derived from then it should be virtual (and it should also make the destructor virtual).

Comment: You say "If they do not want this to be derived from then it should not be virtual" but a non-virtual method does not _prevent_ a derived class from overriding it, it just means the new method cannot be used via a base class pointer. If necessary the derived class can call the base class method.